# Return one or the other javascript

Tags: javascript, string, character, reduce

A function takes one string argument and outputs a string.

It should remove all vowels from the supplied string if the string contains mostly vowels, otherwise return the supplied string without modification.

Specification:

- A string is considered to contain mostly vowels if it has more vowels (a, e, i, o, u) than consonants (b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z), ignoring all non-alphabetic characters from the count.
- If a string contains mostly vowels, the result should have excess whitespace removed - there should be no leading or trailing whitespace, nor any double spaces within the returned string.
- Strings may contain more than one word. Spaces between words must be preserved, except for when the entire word has been removed.

For example, the string "hello" would remain hello.

However, the string "adieu" would become d.

This is what I have tried to no success so far:

```
    function removeVowel(input) {
   //function that takes string as input
    //function returns an object containing vowel count without case in account.
    function vowelCount(input) {
        //to get vowel count using string.match
        let arrVowels =input.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g);

        //acc=accumulator, curr=current value
        let countVowCons= arrVowels.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
           if (typeof acc[curr.toLowerCase()] == 'undefined') {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] = 1;
           } 
           else {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] += 1;
           }
           return acc;
           // the blank object below is default value of the acc (accumulator)
           }, {}); 

        countVowCons.NonVowels= input.match(/[^aeiouAEIOU]+?/g).length;
             
        if(arrVowels > countVowCons.NoVowels) {
          //remove vowels from string & return new string
          const noVowels = input.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '')
        } else {
          // return supplied string withoout modification
          return input
        }      
      } 
}
```

I know I´m doing a lot of things wrong, could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Expected: "hello"
Received: undefined
```

```
Expected: "hrd d"
Received: undefined
```

Comment: okay, so after I posted the solution, here are some comments. Look further into RegEx, i.e - the "i" flag means case insensitive, so in order to search for both lower and upper case, add it as a flag. The caret symbol inside the brackets [^abcdef] means - NOT. If you should go ahead in the JS world look a bit more into the syntax of it. You don't seem to need to collect the count of EACH vowel, don't do it. Try to learn how JS evaluates expressions. for example, undefined is "falsy", so (typeof acc[curr.toLowerCase()] == 'undefined') and simply (acc[curr.toLowerCase()]) would be falsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const maybeDisemvowel = (originalString) => {
  const onlyConsonants = originalString.replace(/[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxys]/gi, '')
  const onlyVowels = originalString.replace(/[^aeoiu]/gi, '')
  const withoutVowels = originalString.replace(/[aeoiu]/gi, '')
  const shouldReturnOriginal = onlyConsonants.length > onlyVowels.length
  return shouldReturnOriginal
    ? originalString
    : withoutVowels.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
}

console.log(maybeDisemvowel('  abb     b')) // no change
console.log(maybeDisemvowel('aaaaaa   bbb aaa bbb b')) // change
console.log(maybeDisemvowel('aa    ab       bba ')) // change
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const transform = string => {
  const letters = string.replace(/\W/gi, '')
  const notVowels = letters.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '')

  if(letters.length < notVowels.length * 2){
    return string
  }

  return  string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '').split(' ').filter(word => word).join(' ').trim()
} 

console.log(transform('hello'))


console.log(transform('Adieu'))

console.log(transform('Adieu hello aaaaaaaaaaaa b'))

console.log(transform('I heard a ad'))
```

Comment: That doesn't ignore non-letters as per the question. I like the approach though.

Comment: I made the same error by not reading the entire post.

Comment: this is working but it´s giving me an error, it´s leaving an empty space at the beginning of the string that shouldn´t be there      ````Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "hrd d"
Received: " hrd d"   ```

Comment: @Mary1993 if the string is not trasformed the original string is returned as the OP requested

Comment: i have added this  ```.return notVowels.replace(/^\s+/g, '');```. This removes the empty space at the beginning and now it passes both tests! Thanks a lot R4ncid! Could you explain the *2

Comment: @Mary1993 - Just a minor point about the above: The `\W` in the first regex will allow `_` and digits in addition to English letters. You might want to replace it with `[^a-z]` (or whatever alphabet you're using, if not the English one).

Answer (score 0):

function maybeDisemvowel() is not nesccesary and its not passing value into that other function.

```js
//pass input Pneumonia
function vowelCount(input) {
    //to get vowel count using string.match
    let arrVowels = input.match(/[\saeiouAEIOU]+?/g);
    //arrVowels = ['e', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'a']

    // now simply compare length of input minus all vowels
    // with vowels you found in word
    // inp 9 - arrVow 5 < 5
    // 4 < 5 => true

    //you tried compare with variable that was not defined before
    //that value was in if statement which is out of reach
    if (input.length - arrVowels.length < arrVowels.length) {
        //remove vowels from string & return new string

        //you forget return this value
        return input.replace(/[\saeiouAEIOU]/gi, '');
    } else {
        // return supplied string withoout modification
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's been fixed, thanks!